# AngularJS - ui.calendar TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, calendar

I am creating a calendar with full calendar which pulls the events from an external json file. I am getting the following error;

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at Object.changeWatcher.getTokens (calendar.js:98)
at n.a.$get.n.$digest (angular.js:14300)
at n.a.$get.n.$apply (angular.js:14571)
at angular.js:1455
at Object.e [as invoke] (angular.js:4203)
at d (angular.js:1453)
at uc (angular.js:1473)
at Jd (angular.js:1367)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (angular.js:26304)
at n.Callbacks.j (jquery.js:3099)
```

on my angularJS app.

At the minute my event source looks like this;

```
[ [ { "title": "Public Holiday", "start": "2015-09-07", "allDay": true },
{ "title": "Public Holiday", "start": "2015-09-08", "allDay": true } ] ]
```

This I believe is true but as I am also able to run the .length function on it. However I am not too sure where I am going wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module('app',['ui.calendar']);
app.controller('mainController',function($scope,cacheFactory,$interval,holiday){
holiday.allHolidays(function(data){

    var len = data.data.length;
    var friendArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){

        if(data.data[i].array_phasedescription1stline__tspending_jobandphase == 'Public Holiday'){

            friendArray.push({
                title: data.data[i].array_phasedescription1stline__tspending_jobandphase,
                start: data.data[i].tspending_timedate,
                allDay: true
            });
        }
    }
    $scope.events = [friendArray];
});

$scope.calOptions = {
    editable: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'next'
    }
}
});
```

factories.js

```
app.factory('holiday',function($http){
return {
   allHolidays: function(callback){
       $http.get('schedule.json').success(callback);
   }
```

}
    });

index.html

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="mainController">
    <div class="calendar" ui-calendar="calOptions" ng-model="events"></div>
    {{ events | json}}
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Why do you use array notations in $scope.events = [friendArray] ? It is already an array, why the paranteses?

Comment: whilst trying to find an answer i stumbled upon a similar example which had an array in an array so I gave it a try, I am afraid it also does not work removing the [] from the $scope.events

Comment: Did you look at calendar.js line 98?

Comment: I am having the same issue but my data source looks slightly different: `dataSources = [{events: [{...},{...}]}]`. This is, according to the docs, the way to do it. Anyway it doesn't work so I keep on looking. You might have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066056/angular-ui-calendar-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23066056/angular-ui-calendar-typeerror-cannot-read-property-length-of-undefined)

Answer (score 0):

You are defining `$scope.events` way too late. It the controller is started and the events source var is not when the `ui-calendar` directive is processed, it will trigger the error. Probably a bug or a feature :)

Try this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.calendar']);

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, cacheFactory, $interval, holiday) {

  // Event sources array is created here 
  $scope.events = [];

  $scope.calOptions = {
    editable: true,
    header: {
      left: 'prev',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'next'
    }
  }

  holiday.allHolidays(function (data) {
    var len = data.data.length;
    var friendArray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
      if(data.data[i].array_phasedescription1stline__tspending_jobandphase == 'Public Holiday'){
        friendArray.push({
          title: data.data[i].array_phasedescription1stline__tspending_jobandphase,
          start: data.data[i].tspending_timedate,
          allDay: true
        });
      }
    }

    // We don't create the array here, we modify it, triggering the watch
    $scope.events.push(friendArray);
  });
});
```